# Git - will the file moves be detected?

Tags: git

I performed some modifications on a branch (A).

I then decided to create a brand new branch (B) based on the state of my existing working copy and commit and push to that.

There were a number of files that had been moved during my earlier refactoring, and hence were now not included in version control having been moved directly in the filesystem. By accident I did not add these files to git before committing and pushing to the new branch (B).

If I now add these files and commit and push, will Git be able to detect the file move operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not if they're done as two separate commits, because the files will have been deleted in one revision and a new file created in the new revision. If you want to preserve the rename, you should do a `git commit --amend` to append your additions to the previous commit with the deletions.

Comment: I added the files and performed a *git commit --amend*. Committing this resulted in conflicts which I resolved using mine (i.e. the *add* instead of the *delete*). GitHub no longer displays the file history. Will the file move be detected when I come to pull in other branches? If so, I can live with the temporary loss of visible file history.

Comment: For info: pulling in other branches does not seem to restore the visible file history.

Comment: @Ben: Do have a look at bdonlan's answer. Since git does its rename detection per-operation, it will detect this as a rename if and only if appropriate. If you examine just one of your commits, then of course it won't show up as a rename - that commit doesn't contain a rename, just a deletion or addition! But if you compare a commit before the rename to one after it, then it'll be detected as normal - it's just a comparison of two states, independent of what commits came between.

Answer (score 3):

The move will be detected if you do a direct comparison between before and after revisions, but not if you view a regular `git log`:

```
[bd@satoko testgit] echo hello world > foo
[bd@satoko testgit] git init
gitInitialized empty Git repository in /home/bd/testgit/.git/
[bd@satoko testgit] git add foo
[bd@satoko testgit] git commit -m 'test'
[master (root-commit) 772dbe5] test
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
[bd@satoko testgit] mv foo bar
[bd@satoko testgit] echo baz > quux
[bd@satoko testgit] git add quux
[bd@satoko testgit] git commit -a -m 'rm; add'
[master 59dd10b] rm; add
 2 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 foo
 create mode 100644 quux
[bd@satoko testgit] git add bar
[bd@satoko testgit] git commit -m 'add'
[master 823f70f] add
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar

[bd@satoko testgit] git log --stat -m
commit 823f70fe50828204686a6a42a5e98dc9b258903b
Author: Bryan Donlan <bdonlan@fushizen.net>
Date:   Mon Jan 17 05:06:16 2011 -0500

    add

 bar |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

commit 59dd10bfb72bb9005edecb1b7609978d82d21652
Author: Bryan Donlan <bdonlan@fushizen.net>
Date:   Mon Jan 17 05:05:58 2011 -0500

    rm; add

 foo  |    1 -
 quux |    1 +
 2 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

commit 772dbe5357253b533f8f2b9c64836dc09a51def4
Author: Bryan Donlan <bdonlan@fushizen.net>
Date:   Mon Jan 17 05:04:35 2011 -0500

    test

 foo |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
### As you can see, a log doesn't show the move, but...
[bd@satoko testgit] git diff --stat  823f..772d -M
 bar => foo |    0
 quux       |    1 -
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
### A direct comparison does
```

This behavior is because git does not actually save move/rename information - it reconstructs it by comparing the contents of added/removed files. With a direct comparison, it only looks at the before/after state, so exactly how the files were added/removed doesn't matter. However, with `git log`, it compares pairwise revisions, so it only ever sees either 'removed' or 'added', not both.

If this is a problem, you may want to consider using [`git rebase --interactive`](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) to merge the add of the files back into the revision that deleted them. However, this can have [unwanted side effects](http://changelog.complete.org/archives/586-rebase-considered-harmful) if the revisions with the bad history have already been downloaded by others.

Answer (score 0):

But git treats objects by content and not by paths. That means it does not make a difference when you move an object (a file) or delete/add an object. It will be stored only once in the git repo database.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Git does not store any renaming information, but rather runs some sort of rename detection mechanism you should be fine. See also [Handling renames: svn vs. git vs. mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537616/handling-renames-svn-vs-git-vs-mercurial)

Comment: It would seem in my case, although the history might be available, file revision history appears lost from a tool like GitHub, presumably because of the number or revisions the comparison is made over.